# error: 'Could not solve for environment specs' while creating a conda environment. despite seemingly having all the channels and dependencies

Tags: virtualenv, anaconda3

**command that triggers error:** conda env create --file hf-env.yml

**My error (Anaconda Prompt)**
Could not solve for environment specs
The following packages are incompatible:

- argon2-cffi-bindings ==21.2.0 py310h90acd4f_3
- ...
- ...

**.YML File**

```
name: hf-env
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - argon2-cffi-bindings=21.2.0=py310h90acd4f_3
  - ...
  - ...
```

When i first  saw this It seemed to me that these dependencies are not in the channels.
so i snooped around in my anaconda files (conda-meta) and i did find a file that was identical to one of the  dependencies that was listed namely: argon2-cffi-bindings=21.2.0=py310h90acd4f_3.

I'm still new so I'm assuming that the defaults channel get's its dependencies from the folder named: conda-meta (i could be wrong)

I get the sense that there is something very obvious i am missing but im not sure.

How do i fix this error?